# get a value of selected item in $_POST

Tags: php, html

i have a `dropdown`that fill dynamic with ajax,

```
<select id="singer_list">
  <option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>
    </select>
```

my problem is: i can't get a Value of `dropdown` on the `$_POST`
i'm using:

```
$singer_name=$_POST["singer_list"];
echo $singer_name;
```

but `$singer_name` is show nothing!
how to select value of `dropdown` in `$_POST`?

my ajax code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#genre_list").change(function(){
        var genre_id=$("#genre_list").val();
        $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url:'ajax_singer_list.php',
             data:{'genre_id':genre_id},
             success:(function(data){
                     $("#singer_list").append(data);
                 })

            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

ajax_singer_list.php handler:

```
<?php
include('../db_inc.php');
$genre_id =$_POST['genre_id'];
$result = $connection->query("SELECT singer_name,singerid from singers INNER JOIN genre_singer ON singers.singerid=genre_singer.f_singer_id where f_genre_id = '$genre_id'")or die($connection->error);
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $singer_name = $row->singer_name;
            $singer_id = $row->singerid;
            echo "<option value=$singer_id>$singer_name</option>";
            }
            $connection->close;
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using Ajax at all

Comment: have you tried a var_dump($_POST['singer_list']);?

Comment: Well, the question says it is filled with ajax, not posted by it? :)

Comment: Put the name attribute on every option. The name will be the index of the `$_POST` array.

Comment: write your complete code here

Comment: i'm add `ajax` and `ajax_singer_list.php` handler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from if you actually post etc, the first thing is:
if you want to post a `<select>`, you need to give it a **name**, not just an 'id'.

```
 <select id="singer_list" name="singer_list" >
```